# VSCode: Python running in terminal shows many dirs

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal

Every time I run a python code in VSCode the terminal shows several dirs, like: the project directory, the venv directory and the python file that's being executed, like this:

```
(.venv) E:\Python\projetos\Projeto Scraping>"e:/Python/projetos/Projeto Scraping/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "e:/Python/projetos/Projeto Scraping/app/scraper.py"
```

Is there a method to shorten this?

Comment: why bother, this way it ALWYS works, otherwise we would get a lot of questions of users that can't run the stuff because they have no clue what they are doing

Comment: Before reinstalling vscode it was normal, this was very strange when I tried to run my code, I will use the code runner that circodid mentioned below

Comment: No this the normal behavior, it shows you what is needed to run the script

Answer (score 1):

Try using Code Runner Extension, and you can use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `N` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.**

After downloading and installing, add the following configuration to your `settings.json` file and you will get clean output in the **OUTPUT** panel.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

[image]